# ALTER TABLE COUNTER Invalid field data type

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
db.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & strTableName & " ALTER COLUMN " & strIndexName & " COUNTER(1,1)"
```

Gives me a Invalid field data type error.

The field is AutoNumber.

Isn't what COUNTER is suppose to address?

Goal here is to reset newly recreated (via DAO) AutoNumber field to 1 without having to compact and repair remote database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS Access run-time error 3259 invalid field data type on alter table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659444/ms-access-run-time-error-3259-invalid-field-data-type-on-alter-table)

Answer (score -1):

You can only define a COUNTER field when creating a table. I don't really get what you're conveying when you say the field is autonumber; If it is this, then what are you hoping to achieve with this statement? The goal doesn't (in my mind) seem to make a lot of sense; Compacting and repairing a remote database sounds easier - though that is unlikely to achieve what it is you seem to want to achieve.

If the table is empty, drop it and re-create it. If it isn't empty - does the value of the ID field matter? If it does, there isn't much you can do easily. If it doesn't matter, you could create a new table with the same structure, and insert all of the existing table's rows in (excluding the current counter/autonumber column) then drop the existing table.